# Struggling with my first 'in-depth' directive: an image/video gallery

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to build a relatively simple gallery as a directive so I can use it on a couple different templates on my site. Here' what I have so far. The item attr accepts a json object which will contain an 'images' array of objects, each with a url and a label. It also has an optional video property containing a youtube video id. I have a separate youtube embed directive already working that this gallery can use. The $scope.gallery object is intended to contain information about the current state of the gallery as well as functions to modify it. I'm having trouble accessing the item object from within my gallery object. I'm not sure that I'm using the linking function correctly.

```
app.directive('gallery', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {item: '='},
        templateUrl: './app/directives/templates/gallery.html',
        link: function ($scope, elem, attrs) {


            // this works

            console.log($scope);


            /* this logs 'undefined' even though the
            previous log shows a non empty item property */

            console.log($scope.item);


            $scope.gallery = {
                currentImage: 0,
                video: false,

                /* I need to set count equal to the number 
                of images in a given item, but again can't access
                $scope.item to see the images property */

                count: 5,
                next: function () {
                    if (this.video === true) {
                        if (this.currentImage < $scope.item.images.length) {
                            this.currentImage += 1;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (this.currentImage < $scope.item.images.length -1) {
                            this.currentImage += 1;
                        }
                    }
                },
                previous: function () {
                    if (this.currentImage > 0) {
                        this.currentImage -= 1;
                    }
                },
                select: function (index) {
                    this.currentImage = index;
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you use some Developer Tools like that of Chrome, right?

In the devtools, if you `console.log()` an object which is not a primitive value, it will be a dynamic presentation, that means the inner fields will be evaluated only when you read it. Instead, for a primitive value, including undefined, it will be printed as string immediately. When your code was run, `$scope.item` may have not got the object (sometimes the values are requested remotely right?). But that happened very soon after that. So this is why you can see `item` in `$scope` but `$scope.item` is undefined.

I would suggest that you change all `this` reference in your functions to $scope.gallery .

Comment: What is the difference between 'this' and $scope.gallery in this situation when 'this' is already referencing an angular $scope object?

Comment: And with this race condition being an issue how can I set the count property of my gallery object to $scope.item.images.length?

Comment: @Constellates In your case `this` is identical to `$scope.gallery`, but I still suggest that because it leads to less confusion. In your case, I would suggest that you directly access `$scope.item.images.length` instead of maintain an own `count` field. Or, you may also use (quite ugly) `scope.$watch()` to watch the changes to your `item` model.